# $GLOBALS output while register_globals = off

Tags: php

register_globals is set "off".

phpinfo():
Local Value = Off

Master Value = Off

```
$var = "test";
function test()
{
    var_dump($GLOBALS["var"]);  // this prints "test"..
    die;
}
test();
```

Why do I get the output of $GLOBALS["var"] ?

```
$test = "mytext";
echo $GLOBALS["test"];  // output: "mytext".. why?
die;
```

Thanks for information!

Comment: Right, putting `global $var;` inside your function would also allow you to use it like a global variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `register_globals` controls whether `$_GET`, `$_POST`, cookie, environment and server parameters are automatically registered as globals or not. It does not disable the `$GLOBALS` variable; that's a core PHP mechanism that cannot be switched off.

Comment: [register_globals](http://php.net/register_globals), and more in-depth: [Using Register Globals](http://php.net/manual/en/security.globals.php)